# What is the correct way in Migrating CodeIgniter files from WAMP to LAMP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, wamp, lamp

I have made a web app using **CodeIgniter 2.1.3** with **PHP 5.4.24** and **EasyPHP 14.1** on **WAMP**. Now, I want to transfer my server on **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** using this [**LAMP tutorial**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu). Everything works fine except my *web app stops on working*. It can parse simple scripts though like when creating new CI file. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here's what the log says:

`The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.`

`HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 15ms`

Answer (score 1):

There may be errors on your page. You can display them by adding the following lines to the **top** your main index file, be it `index.php` or `backend.php`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Also, check if you have enabled `mod_rewrite` in your apache config.

Comment: when it was on my WAMP server, it has no errors. Ill try to check if there is on LAMP. By the way, why do I need to enable mod_rewrite and how?

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is an apache module that is used by codeigniter to route your urls. And the `.htaccess` file in your project directory usually contains directives like `RewriteEngine On`. This needs `mod_rewrite` to work. You can check if its enabled by typing `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep rewrite_module` in your shell. You should see something like `rewrite_module (shared)`. if not, then enable it. You can see how to do that here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/5758551/4274918](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5758551/4274918)

Comment: hey, also ive noticed my .htaccess files are missing when uploaded to my lamp server. where can i find or let them be visible again?

Comment: i can see that my `mod_rewrite` is already enabled, checked it and displayed `rewrite_module (shared)` thank you for that! but, still not fixing my problem

Comment: This error may be caused by a lot of things, from improper file permissions to parse errors. Try looking at `/var/log/apache2/access.log` and `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for more information. And did you try displaying all errors, did you find anything there?

Comment: Regarding `.htaccess`, if you are new to linux, files prefixed with a dot `.` are hidden. to show them, `cd` to your project directory in the terminal and do `ls -a -l` to show all files.

Comment: somehow i got to stop showing encoding error by uncommenting AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 at /etc/apache2/conf.d but im still getting HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error